# clearTimeout not working for popover variable undefined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timeout, coffeescript, popover

Ok so i have some coffeescript in users.js.coffee which runs a twitter bootstrap popover on scrolling over a username (this is currently working) now what i want to be able to do is use a timeout to hide the popover if a user does not mouse over the popover.

Here is my code (currently throwing Uncaught ReferenceError: timeoutObj is not defined on scrollover of the popover) my problem is obviously with the timeoutObj variable although it should be set in the mouseleave method?

```
$ ->
 timeoutObj = undefined
 $(".comment-user-name").popover({
   trigger: "manual"
   placement: 'top'
   template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="clearTimeout(timeoutObj);$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide(); });"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
 })
 $(".comment-user-name").mouseenter((event, ui) ->
   $(".comment-user-name").popover('show') 
 )
 $(".comment-user-name").mouseleave((event, ui) ->
   timeoutObj = setTimeout (-> $(".comment-user-name").popover('hide') ), 3000
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct code:

```
$ ->
      timeoutObj = null
      $(".comment-user-name").popover(
          {
          trigger  : "manual"
          placement: 'top'
          template : '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
          }
      )

      $(".popover").onmouseover(
          (event, ui) ->
              clearTimeout(timeoutObj)
              $(this).mouseleave(-> $(this).hide())
      )
      $(".comment-user-name").mouseenter((event, ui) -> $(".comment-user-name").popover('show'))
      $(".comment-user-name").mouseleave((event, ui) -> timeoutObj = setTimeout (-> $(".comment-user-name").popover('hide') ), 3000)
```

You can not use timeoutObj in `'<div class="popover" onmouseover="...`